# How To Add The "Change Owner" Button Inside Lightning Record Page?

Tags: quickaction, owner, lightning-record-page, record-owner, dynamic-actions

I have a requirement in which **I must add the standard "Change Owner" button inside a lightning record detail page**. I know that this button appears inside list-views, but I need to show the button when someone is seeing the details of the record (an standard object called ResidentialLoanApplication).

**Can I do this using Dynamic Actions?** I tried upgrading the Highlights Panel to use Dinamic Actions, but I cannot choose the "Change Owner" button. I can only add the "Sharing" button, and however, this "Sharing" button doesn't appear, even when the user has the "**Transfer Records**" permission granted.

If there's no standard way of doing this , then  I'd like to have some documentaion to support this so I can show my colleguees and change the requirement to move to a custom LWC.

Thank you very much. Any insight would be appreciated.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I finally could acomplish my requirement. I created the action myself, adding a new action of type "Update a Record" and adding the only the Owner to the layout.

Later I went to the LIghtning Record Page > click on edit > click on the Hightlighs Panel component > click on "Updgrade" to Dyanmic Actions > Then I added my new action to the panel and confogured the visibility filter. It's working fine.

Essentially I followed this steps:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.case_interaction_update_case_owner_quick_action.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5

Hope this help somebody. Regards.